# String.fromCharCode only works with one character

Tags: javascript, string, character, fromcharcode

I have javascript code:

> s = String.fromCharCode(s);

This works but it only works with one character even though the String.fromCharCode method is supposed to work with multiple characters seperated by commas.  Any ideas why this is?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(65, 66);` works

Comment: I does work fine with multiple parameters, so the problem has to be somewhere else. What does the code look like that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more than one character, you'll want to pass a sequence of values...

```
String.fromCharCode(65, 66, 67);  // "ABC"
```